# Can not get Materialize css dropdown to work with dynamically loaded modal

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, materialize

I have a Rails application running with MaterializeCSS. I am generally using materialize many places in the app including JS objects (like FAB buttons) and it all works fine...except for the dropdown button.

I have this one section of code where I load a [modal form](http://materializecss.com/modals.html) on the modal form I have two  materializecss components which requires JS: 1) a collapsible list and 2) a dropdown. The collapsible list works fine, but the dropdown does not.

The following code makes it run (or not :-( ). I'm using coffeescript and haml:

this initializes the modal:

```
modalInit: () ->
  $('#photo-modal').modal
    dismissible: true
    opacity: .5
    in_duration: 300
    out_duration: 200
    starting_top: '4%'
    ending_top: '10%'
    ready: (modal, trigger) ->
      App.PhotoTaginput.refresh()
      $('.collapsible').collapsible();
      $('.dropdown-button').dropdown();
```

Note that the collapsible and the dropdown are initialized in the same way!!

I load the modal with this script:

```
showModal: (element) ->
  _this = this
  photoId = $(element).parents('.photo-widget').data("photoid")
  url = '/photos/' + photoId + '?view=modal'
  $('#photo-modal > .modal-content').load url, (result) ->
    $('#photo-modal').modal('open');
```

This fetches some HTML which looks like this:

```
.row
  .image_info#photo_id{:photo_id=>@photo.id, "data-photo_id"=>@photo.id}
    .col.l5
      .modal-toolbar
        %a.waves-effect.waves-light.btn.like{:type => "button", :class=>current_user.voted_for?(@photo) && "red"}
          %i.fa.fa-thumbs-o-up
        %a.dropdown-button.btn{"data-activates" => "dropdown1", :href => "#"} Drop Me!
        %ul#dropdown1.dropdown-content
          %li
            %a{:href => "#!"} one
          %li
            %a{:href => "#!"} two
          %li.divider
          %li
            %a{:href => "#!"} three

    .col.l12#modal_image
      %img.bg.responsive-img{:src => "#{@photo.url('org')}"}



    %ul.collapsible.overlay-menu.overlay-menu-show{"data-collapsible"=>"accordion"}
      %li
        .collapsible-header.overlay-menu-header
          %i.material-icons info
          info
        .overlay-menu-body.collapsible-body
          %table
            %tbody
              %tr
                %td Date
                %td=@photo.date_taken_formatted
              %tr
                %td ID
                %td=@photo.id
              %tr
                %td Country
                %td=@photo.location.country
              %tr
                %td Model
                %td=@photo.model
              %tr
                %td Make
                %td=@photo.make
```

It must have something to do with the JS which dynamically should initialize the dropdown. I say this because I can see that the css on the  of the dropdown does not change when I press the button. It's kind of wierd though cause it is initialized the same way as the collapsible.

I'm pretty sure that the jquery and materialize libs are loaded correctly. I'm already using both libs in other code sections throughput the application

Comment: Can you post the HTML rendered source of the dropdown? It could help to check if all attributes are on the right place. Another test that you could do is calling `$('.dropdown-button')` and `$('.dropdown-button').dropdown()` in the inspector to see what happens

Comment: do you use turbolinks?

Comment: @Mat Dear sir... ;-) you solved it for me - indirectly. when I called `$('.dropdown-button')`  I realised that I had loaded the dropdown several times resulting in the id of the <ul> being repeated several times - that screwed up the initialisation. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be some HTML beef up.

I had accidentally loaded this part several times times:

```
    %a.dropdown-button.btn{"data-activates" => "dropdown1", :href => "#"} Drop Me!
    %ul#dropdown1.dropdown-content
      %li
        %a{:href => "#!"} one
      %li
        %a{:href => "#!"} two
      %li.divider
      %li
        %a{:href => "#!"} three
```

this resulted in several id's of `#dropdown1` in the HTML this screwed up the initialisation of the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](http://materializecss.com/dropdown.html#!) says you have to initialize it when you create it dynamycally.

> jQuery Plugin Initialization
>
> Initialization for dropdowns is only necessary if you create them
>   dynamically.
>
> ```
>   $('.dropdown-button').dropdown({
>       inDuration: 300,
>       outDuration: 225,
>       constrain_width: false, // Does not change width of dropdown to that of the activator
>       hover: true, // Activate on hover
>       gutter: 0, // Spacing from edge
>       belowOrigin: false, // Displays dropdown below the button
>       alignment: 'left' // Displays dropdown with edge aligned to the left of button
>     }
>   );
> ```

Comment: I initialise it in the modalInit function. It has a callback function that gets called when the modal is loaded

Answer (score 0):

my dropdown menu was loaded only once after updating the page, I solved it by inserting the two methods at the same time.

```
data-activates="dropdown1"
data-target="dropdown1"
```

```
<!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
<li class ="hoverable"><a class="dropdown-trigger" data-activates ="dropdown1" data-target="dropdown1"><%= current_user.email %><i class="material-icons left">perm_identity</i></a></li>
```